# jquery keydown event detector not detecting keypresses?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been making another project, and I was using something that was working fine in a previous code: $(document).keydown(function(keypressed){});, something I used to detect certain keys being pressed.
However, though it still works in my previous project, in this new one it seems to read over it once and then not detect when a key is down. Does anyone know what's up?

```js
var plrPosTest = 6;
$(document).keydown(function(keyPressed){
 if (keyPressed.keyCode == 65 && plrPosTest != 1){ // A
  plrPosTest -= 1;
 } else if (keyPressed.keyCode == 68 && plrPosTest != 6){ // D
  plrPosTest += 1;
 }
    console.log(plrPosTest);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: I am linking the jQuery library properly.

Comment: I've converted your code block into a Stack Snippet ([here's how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). When I run it, holding down A repeatedly lowers the value until it hits 1 and stays there, and holding down D repeatedly raises the value until it hits 6 and stays there. That sounds like the behavior you've indicated you want. Please update the snippet or the question to clarify.

Comment: What I mean is that the program reads over the code once, but then the keydown will not trigger when a key is pressed or down.

Comment: @Taplar - `keydown` repeating isn't new, no. :-) I didn't know about `keypress` either (or `beforeinput`). Interesting!

Comment: That suggests that the document doesn't have focus. Certainly if I ensure the focus is in the Stack Snippet document when I run it, again, I get the behavior you've seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently; it wasn't the keydown event detector, but rather (in the original code, in the A & D if statements), there was a check for a Boolean (which I had forgotten about), which was set to true (and the if statements were checking for false).